# Using AVAudioRecorder on Mac

Tags: objective-c, macos, avaudiorecorder, avaudiosession

The AVAudioRecorder Class Reference found here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioRecorder_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008238

says that AVAudioSession can be used to configure the audio session

> To configure an appropriate audio session for recording, refer to AVAudioSession Class Reference and AVAudioSessionDelegate Protocol Reference.

But the AVFoundation Framework lacks the AVAudioSession on OS X.

So we get the error, `use of undeclared identifier AVAudioSession`.

So I looked into OS X AVFoundation Framework and found out that AVAudioSession.h is missing!

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Looks like there is no AVAudioSession in OSX. I just start a recording & pause it. If i need to play it, i export the paused recording file to m4a using AVExportSession.

Comment: I have made Audio Recorder using command line tool on Mac. But when I record using [AVAudioRecorder record] always show error "[plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID"

Answer (score 0):

Use [Audio Hardware Services](https://developer.apple.com/search/?q=audiohardwareservice) from [AudioToolbox](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiotoolbox) instead of AVAudioSession. Here is the possible solution: [AVAudioSession alternative on OSX to get audio driver sample rate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25556680/avaudiosession-alternative-on-osx-to-get-audio-driver-sample-rate)

I made some small modifications like the lines:

```
AudioDeviceID deviceID;
OSStatus err = AudioHardwareServiceGetPropertyData(kAudioObjectSystemObject, &addr, 0, NULL, &size, &deviceID);
```