# AVAudioSession alternative on OSX to get audio driver sample rate

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, audio, avfoundation

on IOS you can use `[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] sampleRate];` to retrieve the current sample rate used by the audio driver. AVAudioSession does not exist on OSX, so I am wondering how to achieve the same thing on OSX, as I could not find much on the topic.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay,

after some more in depth research *Audio Hardware Services* seems to do the trick on OSX. Here is some example code:

```
//get the default output device
AudioObjectPropertyAddress addr;
UInt32 size;
AudioDeviceID deviceID = 0;
addr.mSelector = kAudioHardwarePropertyDefaultOutputDevice;
addr.mScope = kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal;
addr.mElement = 0;
size = sizeof(AudioDeviceID);
err = AudioHardwareServiceGetPropertyData(kAudioObjectSystemObject, &addr, 0, NULL, &size, &deviceID);

//get its sample rate
addr.mSelector = kAudioDevicePropertyNominalSampleRate;
addr.mScope = kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal;
addr.mElement = 0;
size = sizeof(Float64);
Float64 outSampleRate;
err = AudioHardwareServiceGetPropertyData(deviceID, &addr, 0, NULL, &size, &outSampleRate);
//if there is no error, outSampleRate contains the sample rate
```

Unfortunately, not as easy as the IOS version, but does the job! This will give you the sample rate settings you can change in the OSX *Audio-MIDI-Setup*.

Comment: Use of undeclared identifier 'deviceID'. What should be it?