# AVAudioSession doesn't exist in AVFoundation framework

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, avfoundation

I am trying to use AVAudioSession in Xcode for my Mac OS application, but Xcode when I try using this code:

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

var recordingSession: AVAudioSession!
```

Xcode gives me a error: "**Use of undeclared type 'AVAudioSession'**"

I have correctly linked the AVFoundation framework to my project, but it still gives that error.

Upon looking into the current AVFoundation framework, I found that AVAudioSession header does not exist inside of AVFoundation.  I have looked all over Google and have found no evidence of anybody else having this issue, and Apple has not deprecated AVAudioSession.

Is AVAudioSession residing in some other framework?

Comment: as mentioned by Mark `AVAudioSession` does not exist for the OSX , another ref: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11867657/4557505

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like AVAudioSession is only available on iOS. Here is the AVFoundation programming guide for Mac:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188

...and the AVFoundation API for Mac:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/navigation/index.html?filter=avfoundation#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Reference

Example from Apple on how to record audio (and video):

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/AVRecorder/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011004

Comment: Wow really?  Thats unfortunate.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any recommendations for functions or tutorials to get audio from audio devices for mac?

Comment: Check out this example: 

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/AVRecorder/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011004

I ran it and tested by recording audio from the mic. It saves it to a .mov file, but you should be able to do whatever you want with the audio.

Comment: Thank you Mark!  That AVRecorder is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score -1):

if you want to check if a class is available for iOS,macos,tvos or watchOS just go to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ and search about your class :

For example :

[image]